# is it possible to get the content (ng-content) of component as string?

Tags: angular, typescript

We are building a design system and for our documentation we would like to display the code next to rendered components.

```
<br-code-example>
  <br-button type="primary">
    Primary default
  </br-button>
</br-code-example>
```

is possible to get what is in ng-content as a string (as well as keep it in ng-content so it gets rendered)?

```
<br-button type="primary">
  Primary default
</br-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we managed to get the results we needed by having the `component.html` of our pages being generated by a node script.

- The `br-code-example` component has an input, `code` that takes in a string with the code.
- Pages are written in markdown (with pieces of `<br-code-example>` html as described in the question.
- A node script runs every time a markdown file is changes that:

  - Goes through each markdown file and searches for `<br-code-example>` tags
  - Takes what is between those tags and adds it as a `code` prop to the `br-code-example`
  - Converts the markdown to html
  - Saves the html as `[page].component.html`

Answer (score 3):

Give a template variable to the `ng-content` tag. And then access it in the Component using [**`ContentChild`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild).

Try this:

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <ng-content #projected></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ContentChild('projected', { static: false }) projectedContent;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('child: ', this.projectedContent.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Example on StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-projected-content-as-html-string?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Tried this, but the problem is you get the rendered html. You don't get `<p> Start editing to see some magic happen :) </p>` but rather `<p _ngcontent-tlc-c2=""> Start editing to see some magic happen :) </p>`. All elements inside the projectedContent are also fully rendered so for me: `<br-button>Click</br-button>` becomes `<br-button _ngcontent-otj-c10="" class="display-contents" type="primary" _nghost-otj-c13="" ng-reflect-type="primary"><button _ngcontent-otj-c13="" class="primary" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><!--bindings={}--> Click<!--bindings={}--></button></br-button>`

Comment: I think I should have asked this earlier. What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? And what's your rationale behind it?

Comment: @SiddAjmera We want to give examples (both code and the result0 for how to use our components. My rationale for having them come from one place is that we know we for sure that code and results match.

Comment: I would recommend putting the code itself into a <code> element and/or using CDATA to avoid the code being parsed